# Set different caption,label,etc function of used language

Tags: languages

I use `tikzpicture` in my document to draw my results and I use an enough generic way that I can reuse my tikz files in various document (article, thesis, beamer...).

I would like to set equivalent caption/label/keyword of my picture for different languages I use (typically english and french) and latex use the good one depending on the used language in the document. I would try the `translator` package but I can't find it anywhere, moreover I am not sure that is the good way to do that.

Is there a way to do that ?

It could look like :

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\def\mycaption{Coucou}
% where \mycaption is different in french and english but I give both captions. 
% For example (but no there is no requirement of the way to do it) :
% \mycaption[english]{Hello}
% \mycaption[french]{Coucou}
\caption{\mycaption} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please make an example of what you want to do?

Comment: so you want to define commands like `\i10nCaption` that takes one argument (language) and returns the term “caption” in your language, so `\i10nCaption{english}` shoul return “caption”, while `i10nCaption{german}` (or `deutsch` if you prefer) should return “Abbildung” (i was too lazy to look up the french term.

Comment: @Ronny: Not really, I want to give two (or more but I don't know a piece of word of german ;-) ) equivalent captions or labels or whatever-you-want in two languages and `babel` or something else can you the right one depending on the language I use in my document. Is it clearer ?

Comment: When i encountered the manual of `translator`, I understood roughly, what you wanted to do.

Comment: If captions are your only problem you could give my `bicaption` package a try.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Thanks for the proposition but actually, it is more to set title, labels, legend entries and so on in both english and french.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the `translator`-Package is available (see for example this [manual](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/translator/translator-manual-en.pdf) ) on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/latex-beamer/files/translator/Version%201.00/) and should do, what you want to do, if i understood you right.
It is also included in the `beamer` [package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer).